# How does Windows identify the network name via Ethernet?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

Recent versions of Windows (7 and newer, i think) seem to be able to identify the network, that they are connected to via Ethernet automatically.

[image: automatically named network]

The name "tbspace Networks" is the WiFi-SSID of the CPE this machine is connected to. But this machine is connected via Ethernet, not via WiFi.

When connecting to a network with a custom DHCP/DNS server this does still work, also configuring a static IPv4/IPv6 address still doesn't change the autodetection.

How does Windows identify the network name?

Can I propagate my own network name with a Linux host?

Comment: you should probalby start here with a description of Network Locations. http://www.digitalcitizen.life/network-locations-explained . It is likely that it was discovered by SSDP or Homegroup features. you can confirm this by turning the network type to Public and rebooting. SSDP and homegroup functions are disabled on Public networks by default.

Comment: @FrankThomas I sniffed the initial discovery process and had a look at the SSDP traffic, and while the routers are listed there, the WiFi name isn't part of the SSDP traffic. How does Homegroup work network-wise? Isn't that handled via SMB? I couldn't see any such traffic -- altough it could be encrypted.

Comment: With a sniffer you can see Text data, but many network services use binary data layouts. while it is possible to sniff them, it will take a protocol intelligent decoder to make sense of the content.

Comment: Try this: Find in the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles`, among the subkeys identify the Ethernet adapter by the item named `ProfileName` and change the name, you might also change `Description`. Note carefully the old values, or better - export the entire subkey as backup. Reboot might be required. I don't have wifi so cannot test this.

Comment: Have you connected to that network before through Wi-Fi?. Not really sure of the following, but maybe Windows cached the SSID and is displaying it now for the Ethernet connection as they both share the same gateway address or MAC?.

Comment: @Jaime Hablutzel: No, the PC has no wifi card.